# Well-pump gate valve replacement

Tags: plumbing, repair

I am replacing some of the galvanized plumbing in our basement and shut of the main supply line pictured below. After cutting away some of the cold water line I have a steady stream of water (filled 5+ gallons so far) and I’ve opened up the water faucets on our second floor. I assumed it was coming from the gate valve, so I tried to tighten it a bit since it’s seemed a bit corroded. It turned a bit and started to turn a little easier after the initial torque—but now it just continues turning. I can hear the water sounds to shift from a varied subtle flow as I turn the valve. At one point it stops but then starts to trickle through again. Does this mean the valve is bad and needs replaced? 
If so, will the water continue flowing after I cut away the pvc to remove the valve and attach a new one? [image: valve][image: system]

Comment: it is unclear why you included the second picture

Comment: No reason really, other than I thought more information might be useful.

Comment: useful information would be the description of the valve purpose .... i am assuming that it is your main shutoff, but assuming anything is a bad thing to do .... no not put additional info into comments, edit the question instead

Comment: Do yourself, and whoever comes next, a favor, and replace with a 1/4 turn ball valve - they are much less prone to this type of failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does this mean the valve is bad and needs replaced?

YES- the symptoms you describe indicate a stripped or broken stem or gate:

[image]

> If so, will the water continue flowing after I cut away the pvc to remove the valve and attach a new one?

YES- in fact, you cannot repair or replace the valve unless you shut off the flow upstream. If you try, A LOT of water will flow.